# pasar datos float de una columna a int

Tags: conversión-de-tipos

necesito  realizar un boxplot de una columna llamada age, como ya suponen el dataset esta con la mayoria de los datos en formato erroneo.
reemplace los datos NaN a 0, pero persisten los .float, que tambien debo pasar a int, para graficarlos.
intente con este codigo

```
data_tres[['age']] = data_tres[['age']].astype(int)

data_tres['age'].dtypes
```

pero no funciona!!!!!

este es el error que arroja:

> ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

gracias, por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

intenta probar

```
data_tres.isnull().sum()
```

para verificar que existan registros null en tu dataset. Luego elimínalos con (ejemplo para la columna "age"):

```
data_tres.drop(data_tres[data_tres.age.isnull()].index, inplace = True)
```

E intenta nuevamente con el astype